# Delete comments with python function

Tags: python

Anybody can advise what could be wrong with my code?

I am trying to make a method that removes the single line comments from the content.

Also, the method should return the single line comments that start with '#'.

```
import os


def deleteComments(file):
    try:
        my_file = open(file, 'r')
        data = my_file.read()
        clean = ""
        comment= 0
            if i[0] == "#":
                comment += 1
            else:
                pass
        with open("clean-", "w") as f:
            f.write(clean)
            f.close()
        my_file.close()
    except:
        print("An error occurred with accessing the files")
        return file


def deleteComment(file):
    try:
        my_file = open(file, 'r')
        data = my_file.read()
        clean = ""
        comment= 0
            if i[0] == "#":
                comment += 1
            else:
                pass
        with open("clean-", "w") as f:
            f.write(clean)
            f.close()
        my_file.close()
    except:
        print("An error occurred with accessing the files")
        return file
```

Answer (score 0):

This should make it work.

```
import os

def deleteComments(file):
    try:
        my_file = open(file, 'r')
        data = my_file.read()
        clean = ""
        comments_count = 0
        for i in data.split('\n'):
            if i[0] == "#":
                clean += i
                clean += '\n'
                comments_count += 1
            else:
                pass
        name = os.path.basename(path)
        with open("clean-" + name, "w") as f:
            f.write(clean)
            f.close()
        my_file.close()
        return comments_count

    except:
        print("An error occurred with accessing the files")
        return file
```